# How to use Modal Bootstrap to confirm delete yes/no?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-modal

I have modal box that should confirm if user wants to delete record or not. SO far I got this to work but I have function inside of the function. This is not recommended as I know in JavaScript so I was wondering if there is another solution to avoid this problem? Here is example:

```js
var myJSON = {
  "customers": [{
      "id": 100,
      "first": "Mike",
      "last": "Johnson",
      "email": "mjohnson@gmail.com",
      "position": "Consultant"
    },
    {
      "id": 101,
      "first": "John",
      "last": "Dunn",
      "email": "jdunn@gmail.com",
      "position": "Programmer"
    },
    {
      "id": 109,
      "first": "Lisa",
      "last": "Morgan",
      "email": "lmorgan@gmail.com",
      "position": "Secretary"
    },
    {
      "id": 233,
      "first": "Kris",
      "last": "Bradley",
      "email": "kbradley@gmail.com",
      "position": "Programmer"
    },
    {
      "id": 57,
      "first": "Dave",
      "last": "Hart",
      "email": "dhart@gmail.com",
      "position": "Supervisor"
    }
  ]
};

$(document).ready(function() {
  generateTbl();
});

function generateTbl() {
  var jsonData = myJSON.customers,
    buildTbl = "<div class='table-responsive'><table class='table table-striped' id='customers'><thead><tr><th>Customer ID</th><th>First Name</th><th>Last Name</th><th>Email</th><th>Position</th><th>Delete</th></thead><tbody>";

  for (var key in jsonData) {
    buildTbl += "<tr id='row_" + jsonData[key].id + "'><td data-id='id'>" + $.trim(jsonData[key].id) + "</td>";
    buildTbl += "<td data-id='first'>" + $.trim(jsonData[key].first) + "</td>";
    buildTbl += "<td data-id='last'>" + $.trim(jsonData[key].last) + "</td>";
    buildTbl += "<td data-id='email'>" + $.trim(jsonData[key].email) + "</td>";
    buildTbl += "<td data-id='position'>" + $.trim(jsonData[key].position) + "</td>";
    buildTbl += "<td class='text-center'><button type='button' class='btn btn-default btn-sm customer_delete'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-remove'></span></button></td></tr>";
  }
  buildTbl += "</tbody></table></div>";
  $('#customers_data').empty().append(buildTbl);
  buildDataTable('customers', [5], 5);
}

function buildDataTable(tblID, columnsArray, displayLength) {
  $('#' + tblID).DataTable({
    dom: 'Bfrtip',
    buttons: [
      'copy', 'csv', 'excel', 'pdf', 'print'
    ],
    "iDisplayLength": displayLength,
    "aoColumnDefs": [{
      'bSortable': false,
      'aTargets': columnsArray
    }]
  });
}

$('#customers_data').on('click', ':button.customer_delete', deleteCustomer);

function deleteCustomer() {
  var recordID = $(this).closest('tr').attr('id'), // Get record ID.
    targetTr = $(this).parents('tr');

  $('#deleteModal').modal('show'); // Show delete modal box.
  $('.confirm_delete').on('click', function() {
    if (recordID) {
      var table = $('#customers').DataTable(); // Select DataTable by ID.
      table.row(targetTr).remove().draw(); // Remove record from DataTable.
    }
  });
}
```

```html
<script language="javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<!-- *** Start: JS and CSS for DataTables. *** -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/js/dataTables.jqueryui.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.4.2/js/dataTables.buttons.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.4.2/js/buttons.flash.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jszip/3.1.3/jszip.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdfmake/0.1.32/pdfmake.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdfmake/0.1.32/vfs_fonts.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.4.2/js/buttons.html5.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.4.2/js/buttons.print.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/css/dataTables.jqueryui.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.4.2/css/buttons.dataTables.min.css" />


<div class="container">
  <div class="panel panel-primary">
    <div class="panel-heading">Welcome to Main Page</div>
    <div class="panel-body">
      <div id="customers_data" class="table-responsive"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="deleteModal" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Confirm Delete</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body" id="delete_modalBody">
        <p>You are about to delete customer record, this procedure is irreversible.</p>
        <p>Do you want to proceed?</p>
        <p class="debug-url"></p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default confirm_delete" data-dismiss="modal">Delete</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

If anyone knows better solution please let me know.

Comment: the only way you can make that better is to not use jquery, besides that, i cant see anything wrong with it?

Comment: @mast3rd3mon Can you explain how that would be better without JQuery? I'm looking for any suggestion that would be better/more efficient.

Comment: jquery is just a bulky library with a horrible naming convention (`$`). i personally would just write it in vanilla js or angular if i wanted multiple pages, services, etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define your `recordID` out of the scope of the function.

Update it's value inside the function and then you'd be able to use it anywhere in your function and when you're able to do that, you can move your function out of the function that handles the click event

here

```js
var myJSON = {
  "customers": [{
      "id": 100,
      "first": "Mike",
      "last": "Johnson",
      "email": "mjohnson@gmail.com",
      "position": "Consultant"
    },
    {
      "id": 101,
      "first": "John",
      "last": "Dunn",
      "email": "jdunn@gmail.com",
      "position": "Programmer"
    },
    {
      "id": 109,
      "first": "Lisa",
      "last": "Morgan",
      "email": "lmorgan@gmail.com",
      "position": "Secretary"
    },
    {
      "id": 233,
      "first": "Kris",
      "last": "Bradley",
      "email": "kbradley@gmail.com",
      "position": "Programmer"
    },
    {
      "id": 57,
      "first": "Dave",
      "last": "Hart",
      "email": "dhart@gmail.com",
      "position": "Supervisor"
    }
  ]
};

$(document).ready(function() {
  generateTbl();
});
var recordID = null;

function generateTbl() {
  var jsonData = myJSON.customers,
    buildTbl = "<div class='table-responsive'><table class='table table-striped' id='customers'><thead><tr><th>Customer ID</th><th>First Name</th><th>Last Name</th><th>Email</th><th>Position</th><th>Delete</th></thead><tbody>";

  for (var key in jsonData) {
    buildTbl += "<tr id='row_" + jsonData[key].id + "'><td data-id='id'>" + $.trim(jsonData[key].id) + "</td>";
    buildTbl += "<td data-id='first'>" + $.trim(jsonData[key].first) + "</td>";
    buildTbl += "<td data-id='last'>" + $.trim(jsonData[key].last) + "</td>";
    buildTbl += "<td data-id='email'>" + $.trim(jsonData[key].email) + "</td>";
    buildTbl += "<td data-id='position'>" + $.trim(jsonData[key].position) + "</td>";
    buildTbl += "<td class='text-center'><button type='button' class='btn btn-default btn-sm customer_delete'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-remove'></span></button></td></tr>";
  }
  buildTbl += "</tbody></table></div>";
  $('#customers_data').empty().append(buildTbl);
  buildDataTable('customers', [5], 5);
}

function buildDataTable(tblID, columnsArray, displayLength) {
  $('#' + tblID).DataTable({
    dom: 'Bfrtip',
    buttons: [
      'copy', 'csv', 'excel', 'pdf', 'print'
    ],
    "iDisplayLength": displayLength,
    "aoColumnDefs": [{
      'bSortable': false,
      'aTargets': columnsArray
    }]
  });
}

$('#customers_data').on('click', ':button.customer_delete', deleteCustomer);

function deleteCustomer() {
 recordID = $(this).closest('tr').attr('id'), // Get record ID.
    targetTr = $(this).parents('tr');
  $('#deleteModal').modal('show');  

}
  $('.confirm_delete').on('click', function() {
    if (recordID) {
      var table = $('#customers').DataTable(); // Select DataTable by ID.
      table.row(targetTr).remove().draw(); // Remove record from DataTable.
    }
  });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>Hearing Application</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <script language="javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script language="javascript" src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <!-- *** Start: JS and CSS for DataTables. *** -->
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/js/dataTables.jqueryui.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.4.2/js/dataTables.buttons.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.4.2/js/buttons.flash.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jszip/3.1.3/jszip.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdfmake/0.1.32/pdfmake.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdfmake/0.1.32/vfs_fonts.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.4.2/js/buttons.html5.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.4.2/js/buttons.print.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/css/dataTables.jqueryui.min.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.4.2/css/buttons.dataTables.min.css" />
  <!-- *** End: JS and CSS for DataTables. *** -->
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="panel panel-primary">
      <div class="panel-heading">Welcome to Main Page</div>
      <div class="panel-body">
        <div id="customers_data" class="table-responsive"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="deleteModal" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
          <h4 class="modal-title">Confirm Delete</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body" id="delete_modalBody">
          <p>You are about to delete customer record, this procedure is irreversible.</p>
          <p>Do you want to proceed?</p>
          <p class="debug-url"></p>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default confirm_delete" data-dismiss="modal">Delete</button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are binding `on click` event every time you click delete `button`. This is **wrong**

**Here is a working solution**

```js
var myJSON = {
  "customers": [{
    "id": 100,
    "first": "Mike",
    "last": "Johnson",
    "email": "mjohnson@gmail.com",
    "position": "Consultant"
  }, {
    "id": 101,
    "first": "John",
    "last": "Dunn",
    "email": "jdunn@gmail.com",
    "position": "Programmer"
  }, {
    "id": 109,
    "first": "Lisa",
    "last": "Morgan",
    "email": "lmorgan@gmail.com",
    "position": "Secretary"
  }, {
    "id": 233,
    "first": "Kris",
    "last": "Bradley",
    "email": "kbradley@gmail.com",
    "position": "Programmer"
  }, {
    "id": 57,
    "first": "Dave",
    "last": "Hart",
    "email": "dhart@gmail.com",
    "position": "Supervisor"
  }]
};

$(document).ready(function() {
  generateTbl();
});

function generateTbl() {
  var jsonData = myJSON.customers,
    buildTbl = "<div class='table-responsive'><table class='table table-striped' id='customers'><thead><tr><th>Customer ID</th><th>First Name</th><th>Last Name</th><th>Email</th><th>Position</th><th>Delete</th></thead><tbody>";

  for (var key in jsonData) {
    buildTbl += "<tr id='row_" + jsonData[key].id + "'><td data-id='id'>" + $.trim(jsonData[key].id) + "</td>";
    buildTbl += "<td data-id='first'>" + $.trim(jsonData[key].first) + "</td>";
    buildTbl += "<td data-id='last'>" + $.trim(jsonData[key].last) + "</td>";
    buildTbl += "<td data-id='email'>" + $.trim(jsonData[key].email) + "</td>";
    buildTbl += "<td data-id='position'>" + $.trim(jsonData[key].position) + "</td>";
    buildTbl += "<td class='text-center'><button type='button' class='btn btn-default btn-sm customer_delete'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-remove'></span></button></td></tr>";
  }
  buildTbl += "</tbody></table></div>";
  $('#customers_data').empty().append(buildTbl);
  buildDataTable('customers', [5], 5);
}

function buildDataTable(tblID, columnsArray, displayLength) {
  $('#' + tblID).DataTable({
    dom: 'Bfrtip',
    buttons: [
      'copy', 'csv', 'excel', 'pdf', 'print'
    ],
    "iDisplayLength": displayLength,
    "aoColumnDefs": [{
      'bSortable': false,
      'aTargets': columnsArray
    }]
  });
}

$('#customers_data').on('click', ':button.customer_delete', deleteCustomer);

var recordID,
  targetTr;

function deleteCustomer() {
  recordID = $(this).closest('tr').attr('id'); // Get record ID.
  targetTr = $(this).parents('tr');

  $('#deleteModal').modal('show'); // Show delete modal box.

}

$('.confirm_delete').on('click', function() {
  if (recordID) {
    console.log('test');
    var table = $('#customers').DataTable(); // Select DataTable by ID.
    table.row(targetTr).remove().draw(); // Remove record from DataTable.
  }
});
```

```html
<script language="javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<!-- *** Start: JS and CSS for DataTables. *** -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/js/dataTables.jqueryui.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.4.2/js/dataTables.buttons.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.4.2/js/buttons.flash.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jszip/3.1.3/jszip.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdfmake/0.1.32/pdfmake.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdfmake/0.1.32/vfs_fonts.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.4.2/js/buttons.html5.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.4.2/js/buttons.print.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/css/dataTables.jqueryui.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.4.2/css/buttons.dataTables.min.css" />


<div class="container">
  <div class="panel panel-primary">
    <div class="panel-heading">Welcome to Main Page</div>
    <div class="panel-body">
      <div id="customers_data" class="table-responsive"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="deleteModal" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Confirm Delete</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body" id="delete_modalBody">
        <p>You are about to delete customer record, this procedure is irreversible.</p>
        <p>Do you want to proceed?</p>
        <p class="debug-url"></p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default confirm_delete" data-dismiss="modal">Delete</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```